# 'field' and 'value' keywords in getters and setters

Tags: kotlin

What's field, value in the getter and setter boilerplate. I am currently doing a crash course on Kotlin, I really didn't understand the significance and usage of the keywords "field" and "value" in Kotlin.

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to understand. Are you askind what's the difference between whats called a field and whats called a value in Kotlin?

Comment: And what do you mean by value? There are no keywords field and value in Kotlin. There are concepts of property and field though. Nice overview of the differences is lined up here https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-programmer-dictionary-field-vs-property-30ab7ef70531

Comment: `field` is a shortcut to given property within the scope of setter/getter, just like `this` is a shourtcut to given class instance within the scope of method. `value` is a shortcut to an argument passed into getter/setter.

Comment: @Alex.T Where does it say that `value` is a keyword?  Isn't it just a normal parameter name (just one that needs no type specified), and so can be renamed to anything you like?

Comment: @Alex.T I'd very much disagree that they are keywords. Keyword can not be used as a variable name, but I can do this in Kotlin ```data class Test(
  val field: String = "Some field",
  val value: String = "Some Value"
)```. They may have some special behaviour in special cases, but they are definitely not keywords.

Comment: @Tarmo & Gidds yeah, makes sense actually, you are both right.

Comment: @Tarmo Kotlin has both [hard keywords](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/keyword-reference.html#hard-keywords) that are always reserved, and [soft keywords](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/keyword-reference.html#soft-keywords) that are reserved in some contexts and available as identifiers in others.  As it happens, both `field` and `value` are soft keywords — but not in this particular context!  Here, `field` is a [special identifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/keyword-reference.html#special-identifiers), while `value` is just a normal identifier that could be changed.

Comment: Wow. Learn something new every day. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare variable e.g `var x = 0` Kotlin implicitly generate it's getter and setter. Unlike Java you have to explicitly add getter setter.

```
var counter = 0 
    set(value) {
        if (value >= 0)
            field = value
    }
```

The word **field** is backing fields and it is used to hold property value(counter) in memory. If you do not add your custom getter setter Kotlin implicitly generate it.